# Broadcast receiver with AIRPLANE_MODE not working with SDK 26

Tags: android, android-broadcast

Normaly, I use a simple code to put a `Toast` when the user change the `AIRPLANE_MODE`, and it work using `targetSdkVersion 25`.

My AirPlaneModeReceiver :

```
    public class AirPlaneModeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "I receive a Broadcast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

The part of the Manifest where I declare my Receiver :

```
<receiver android:name=".AirPlaneModeReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE"/>
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

But when I change the target SDK version to `targetSdkVersion 26`, it's not working at all...
Why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per documentation:

you should remove any broadcast receivers that are registered for implicit broadcast intents.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-migration.html

see Section "Remove broadcast receivers from your manifest file"

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AirplaneModeChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 
        if (isAirplaneModeOn(context.getApplicationContext())) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "AirPlane mode is on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "AirPlane mode is off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```