# BroadcastReceiver not working as I was expecting

Tags: java, android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest

I just wrote this small app to show a small Toast everytime the Airplane Mode was changed. It doesn't work

```
package com.example.android.broadcastreceiverexample;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;
import static android.widget.Toast.*;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
    makeText(context, "Intent detected", LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Here's the manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.android.broadcastreceiverexample">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter tools:ignore="ExtraText">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Is there something that I am missing here, conceptually or in the code?

Comment: Doesn't do anything. As much as I know, when I change Airplane Mode, it should give a Toast, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: which os you testing on? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44919613/broadcast-receiver-with-airplane-mode-not-working-with-sdk-26

Comment: Android Oreo API 26

Comment: You have to programmatically register it to work on Oreo.

Comment: @AswinPAshok is correct, take a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions)

Comment: I did remove the BroadcastReceiver from the manifest file. Still doesn’t work.

Comment: You have to register it in activity. And your app should not be in background, if you want to get the broadcast.

Comment: As in, I should have the app running?